# Ramda compose passing multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

How do we pass multiple inputs to a function inside of a composition?

```
const scaleLinear = R.curry((domain,range,t)=>{
    let [a,b] = domain,
        [c,d] = range;
    return (1 - (t-a)/(b-a))*c + (t-a)(b-a)*d;

//getDomain: arr1 -> [xmin,xmax]
//getRange:  arr2 -> [ymin,ymax]
const scale = R.compose(scaleLinear, getDomain, getRange);
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, but what is the alternative so that I can ultimately pass in 2 pieces of data (arr1,arr2), and get out the appropriate scale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In R.compose only the arity of the right most (bottom) function can be greater than 1. It receives the arguments passed to the composed function, returns a single value, and pass it to the function to it's left, and so on.

In your case you want to transform the arguments of `scaleLinear`, not apply several functions to a value. You can transform the arguments of a function by applying [R.useWith](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith), and an array of transformers:

```
const scale = R.useWith(scaleLinear, [getDomain, getRange, R.identity])
```

Now you you can use `scale` like this:

```
scale(arr1, arr2, 10)
```

Comment: beautiful, I'm getting hooked on fp and ramda, its just more fun